# How do I close Embedded Excel processes in PowerPoint?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I am using VBA to open the open PowerPoint chart data in Excel and perform a series of actions, such as hiding/deleting rows & columns.  I am using the chart.ChartData.Activate command to open the Excel.  I had issues in the past with trying to close the workbook immediately after processing, using Workbook.Close(), so I left the Excels open.  This has now become an issue with larger presentations and it's causing PowerPoint to crash and open back up in Recovery Mode.  Even when I reinstate the Workbook.Close() command, sometimes these instances of Excel still remain open or I lose scope to them inside the routine.

I am processing the presentation on a slide by slide basis so I'm looking for a way to close these open instances all at once, after I'm done processing each slide.

Does anyone know how to access these hanging Excel processes?  I've included a picture to better help explain where they reside.

[image: Task Manager]

I created an example routine below.  I am using the ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow command instead ChartData.Activate b/c when originally designing this, the Activate command caused the full Excel application to open instead of the ChartDataWindow and tremendously slowed down processing and would sometimes crash when repeated over and over again.

I also added an image of PowerPoint with the ChartDataWindows that are left open by my code.

Private Sub ClearColumnsInExcel()

```
'Set the slide
Dim slide As slide
Set slide = pptPres.Slides(1)

'Index through each shape on the slide
Dim shapeX As Integer
For shapeX = 1 To slide.Shapes.Count

    'If this shape has a chart
    If slide.Shapes(shapeX).Type = msoChart Then
    
        'Set the chart
        Dim chart As chart
        Set chart = slide.Shapes(shapeX).chart
        
        'Set the worksheet
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Set wks = chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        'Activate the workbook
        chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow
        
        'Clear target columns
            
        'Remove objects from memomry
        Set wks = Nothing
        Set chart = Nothing
        
    End If
    
Next shapeX
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: Try to create a minimal PowerPoint with perhaps one slide and one or two embedded Excel chart objects, then show us the code you're using that leaves the Excel processes open. We can help better if we can see the actual code logic and sequence. Also, are the charts animated in some way or interactive? If you need the data in Excel to update prior to showing in the PowerPoint, it might help to copy the chart from Excel and paste it onto the slide as an image.

Comment: These charts are not animated yet they may be interactive with the end user.  I don't have the option to paste from Excel.  Our company uses a certain software to end up with these PowerPoint presentations and then I take over and try and clean them up with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you build you code, but you are just closing the workbook. To get the desired outcome, you need to quit the excel application.

I think something like this you do the trick:

```
Private Sub testSave()
    Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlsWbk As Excel.Workbooks

    Set xlsApp = New Excel.Application

    xlsApp.Visible = True
    Set xlswkb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add 'creating a new wokbook just to test

    'do your thing here

    xlswkb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' close workbook without saving in this 
    example
    xlsApp.Quit ' quitting the excel app

End Sub
```